# Работа с Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Ранее работая в среде разработки  - DEV-C++ Для написания таблицы я использовал сочетании клавиш Alt+[введенный код фрагмента таблицы(ASCI-кода)]. К примеру сочетание клавиш Alt+202= "╩". По итогу получался результат, который виден на скриншоте. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После перехода в среду разработки  Visual  Studio 2015 этот принцы перестал работать.

```
 int main()
  {
  float f, x,b,a,c,xn,xk,h;
  int nv;
  int flag, n=1;
  cout<<endl<<"Vvedite xn , xk and h:";
  cin>>xn>>xk>>h;
  if(((xn>xk) && (h>0))||((xn<xk) &&(h<0))||(h==0))
  cout<<endl<<"Vvedeni nevernue znacheniya";
  else{cout<<endl<<"Vvedite a,b,c:";
       cin>>a>>b>>c;
           cout<<endl<<"ЙНННЛНННННННННЛНННННННННЛНННННННННЛНННННННННЛНННННННННЛННННННН\xBB";
           cout<<endl<<"є N є    a    є    b    є    c    є    x    є    f    є Vetka є";
           cout<<endl<<"МНННОНННННННННОНННННННННОНННННННННОНННННННННОНННННННННОННННННН№";
           for(x=xn;((x<=xk)&&(h>0))||((x>=xk)&&(h<0));x=x+h)
           {flag=1;nv=3;
        if ((x<0.)&&(b!=0.)) nv=1;
        if ((x>0.)&&(b==0.)) nv=2;
            switch(nv)
            {case 1:{if(c*x-a==0.) flag=0;
                     else f=-((2*x-c)/(c*x-a));
                     }
                     break;
             case 2:{if(x-c==0.) flag=0;
                     else f=(x-a)/(x-c);
                     }
                     break;
             case 3:{if(c==0 || 2*x==0) flag=0;
                     else f=-(x/c)+(-c/(2*x));
                     }
                     break;
             }//end switch
           if (flag) printf("\nє%-2i є  %-7.2fє  %-7.2fє  %-7.2fє  %-7.2fє  %-7.2fє   %1i   є", n, a, b, c, x, f, nv);
       else printf("\nє%-2i є  %-7.2fє  %-7.2fє  %-7.2fє  %-7.2fє   ****  є   %1i   є", n, a, b, c, x, nv);
       n++;
            }
       cout<<endl<<"ИНННКНННННННННКНННННННННКНННННННННКНННННННННКНННННННННКННННННН\xBC";
      }
   getch();
}//end main
```

Answer (score 0):

Нестыковки с кодировкой. Вы и там, и там работаете под Windows? Тогда скорее всего 866 и 1251 кодировки не стыкуются...

Попробуйте установить нужную локаль.